# Pass a parameter to ssrs from web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am making an mvc3 app.  I have a controller method that saves some data to the database, then it is supposed to pass the id in a url to the company report server, to bring up a single report for that id.

I have tested the report and I can display it by manually entering the id, but when I try passing the id with the url, SSRS returns the error, "parameter is missing a value".

The URL looks like:

```
http://MyServer/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fIGReports%2fMyReport&rs:Command=Render&PersonId=23
```

I am using SSRS 2008.  How do I fix the url so the report sees the PersonId?

Comment: Could you post the code you've written to append the id to the url and then call the url? Also try debugging the application and seeing exactly what the url looks like when it's been called.

Comment: Here is my code, which is now working:                           return Redirect ("http://MyServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/ReportFolder/MyReport&rs:Command=Render&PersonId=" + model.PersonId);
Now I am trying to get it to open a new window, any idea how to do that?

Comment: Hmm, not sure you can do it using C# in the code behind. You may be able to pass the URL onto a webpage then use JQuery or something like that to open a new tab with the URL.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing.  The controller goes to a view, passing in the id.  On the view I wrote an 'onload' jquery script that grabs the ID, builds the URL and does a 'window.open'.  Works great.  If you want to  enter an answer, I give it to you.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is what I ended up doing. The controller goes to a view, passing in the id. On the view I wrote an 'onload' jquery script that grabs the ID, builds the URL and does a 'window.open'. Works great.